# Sticky Service not restarting after RAM full on Xiaomi / Huawei / Lava

Tags: android, android-service

I have a **Sticky Service** and i'm stress testing the app by filling the phone's RAM. Once the RAM is full, the service is destroyed. Since it's a sticky service, it gets restarted automatically when the system has enough resources.

But this happens only on stock android devices like Moto/Nexus. Devices like Xiaomi or Lava do not restart the sticky service, even on 5.1

Is anyone aware of such problems with heavily customized ROMs? Any workarounds to schedule a restart of my service when the memory gets low?

Comment: Huawei has a 'feature' called protected apps where user needs to manually opt-in to let an app run in background -_-
But neither Xiaomi nor Lava have such a thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All stock android devices like works well because they use AOSP ROM's

These devices(HUAWEI,LAVA,XIAOMI) are shipped with pre-installed start managers or energy savers (most of the Huawei devices). If the app is not configured appropriately the services will be killed several seconds/minutes after the screen turns off - or it will not automatically be started after reboot.

Now with the feature called Protected Apps, I tried enabling in my app and still the sticky service is not getting started post the App Kill.
also, furher observation is:-- The HUAWEI device does not even hold a foreground service

Now the possible workaround is:--

> We can use Alarm Manager class to make sure that the service is
>   running when it's necessary. So this Alarm manager can be used to
>   create a timer which checks from time to time if the service should be
>   running and restart it. This time interval needs to be set considering
>   the possible impact on battery consumption.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I went ahead & removed the service altogether, relying instead on play service's alarm manager for my specific needs. Your solution is more like a workaround, but I guess that's the only plausible solution.